Pattern to allow rendering server components within client components
I have a probably pretty common case where a Client Component (CC)  uses the useState hook to conditionally render Server Components (SCs).
A CC will turn any component it imports into CCs, which in this case it is not desired, because they will not work as they should.
I'm imagining there a good pattern to follow in these cases.
How would you handle this simple case? Should the SCs be changed to work as CCs? Should MyPage actually be a SC and somehow use a simpler CC just to handle the tab selection?
MyPage:
'use client'

export default function MyPage() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('A')

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button
          onClick={() => setActiveTab('A')}
        >
          Render A
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => setActiveTab('B')}
        >
          Render B
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {activeTab === 'A' && <ComponentA />}
        {activeTab === 'B' && <ComponentB />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ComponentA:
'use server'

export default async function ComponentA() {
  const data = await getDataForA()

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <span key={item.id}>{item}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ComponentB:
'use server'

export default async function ComponentB() {
  const data = await getDataForB()

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <span key={item.id}>{item}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}


There is similar use case described on the docs. Here:
'use client'
 
import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

The docs say:

<ClientComponent> doesn't know that children will eventually be filled
in by the result of a Server Component. The only responsibility
<ClientComponent> has is to decide where children will eventually be
placed.

And then:
// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponent from './server-component'
 
// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
  )
}

Although in your case inside your client component you might want to use some props other than children like serverCompElementA and serverCompElementB, to easily access the components (you could still use children prop if you want to and then probably it should be possible to access individual children using Children API but AFAIK docs don't encourage to use this API):
// This pattern works:
// You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a
// Client Component.
import ClientComponent from './client-component'
import ServerComponentA from './server-componentA'
import ServerComponentB from './server-componentB'

// Pages in Next.js are Server Components by default
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientComponent serverCompElementA={<ServerComponentA />} serverCompElementB={<ServerComponentB />}/>  
  )
}

This is also specifically allowed based on the docs:

You're not limited to the children prop. You can use any prop to pass
JSX.

Finally, although docs don't have such example specifically and I haven't tested, you should be able to render serverCompElementA and serverCompElementB conditionally within your client component, as you want.
